# data verctorizing of a free text field to get better responses of the prompt

Tags: gpt, vector-database, prompt-engineering

wonder if best practices are existing to approach the solution "what kind of vectorizing of a input filed" is the best for my use-case. Model, size and others can have a significant impact to the results if they are combined by a prompt by genAI. Someone of you know good articles, guidance related on that?
Grre Eric